# R xyplot set facets using cut, how to control order?

Tags: r, lattice

How can I control the order of an R lattice xyplot when the facets are based on a cut? I want them to be in order, high to low, but without me directly entering the levels as the cut breaks can change.

```
df=get(data(iris))
xyplot(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length | cut(Sepal.Width, breaks=4), data=df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really the answer here is "don't use lattice"... meanwhile:

```r
xyplot(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length | cut(Sepal.Width, breaks=4), 
        data=iris, as.table = TRUE)
```

[image: Lattice plot]